# Adding a point every time a div is a certain color, and has been clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, animation

So I am trying to create a game with divs that change color, and give the user a point every time they click on a div that is flashing with color. The user will only get a point if the div is flashing that color, so that condition must be satisfied, I know that for sure. The points will display in another div below the colored divs. I have gotten the divs to change color on an interval, however, I cannot get the point system to work, despite creating an if statement that checks the conditions for background color and whether or not the div has been clicked on. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<STYLE>
.container {
 border: 1px solid black;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 50px;
margin: auto;
 }
   .bigbox {
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100px;
   overflow: scroll;
   border: 1px solid black;
   }
   #bluebox {
   width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    background-color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
   }
 #redbox {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 4px solid black;
 background-color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
 }
#yellowbox {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 4px solid black;
background-color: grey;
display: inline-block;
}
  #greenbox {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 4px solid black;
   background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  }
 </STYLE>
<SCRIPT>
var score = 0;


  function start_game() {
   setTimeout(function() { 
 document.getElementById("redbox").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }, 1000); 

   setTimeout(function() 
   {document.getElementById("redbox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }, 2000);

   setTimeout(function() { 
   document.getElementById("greenbox").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }, 2000);
   setTimeout(function() { 
  document.getElementById("greenbox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
   }, 3000);

     setTimeout(function() { 
   document.getElementById("bluebox").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }, 3000);
    setTimeout(function() { 
   document.getElementById("bluebox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
   }, 4000);    

   setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById("yellowbox").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() { 
   document.getElementById("yellowbox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
   }, 5000);

   setInterval(function(){ start_game() }, 5500);

   if(document.getElementById("redbox").style.backgroundColor = "red" && 
   document.getElementById("redbox").clicked == true) {
   document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =  score + 1;
    alert("You got a point!");
    }

  }


 </SCRIPT>
 <TITLE> Game </TITLE>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
 <DIV class="container">
 <CENTER>
 <DIV id="redbox"> </DIV>
<DIV id="greenbox"> </DIV>
<DIV id="bluebox"> </DIV>
<DIV id="yellowbox"> </DIV>
</CENTER>
</DIV>

 <BR><BR>

  <DIV class="container" style= "background-color: grey;"> <CENTER> <BR> 
  <button onclick="start_game()"> Start game </button> </CENTER> </DIV>
  <BR><BR>

  <DIV class="bigbox">
  Press "Start Game" to begin. <br>
  Score <p id="score"> 0 </p>

 </DIV>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no property called clicked in a div. The proper way is to add an event listener to each div. I will give you an example for one of the divs

```
document.getElementById("redbox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  //e.target is the same div we added the event listener to
  if(e.target.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =  score + 1;
    alert("You got a point!");
  }
});
```

The above runs every time a user clicks on that particular div. The function we are passing as the second argument is the event handler for the click event on that div.

As you have probably already guessed, you will have to add an event listener to every div in order to detect if they were clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This works!

So all I did was changed your code a little so every time you click on a box it does a check to see if the box that was click is in fact 'active' and then if it was it gives you a point.

This is very very buggy though and If I were you I would definitely looking into another library or atleast JQuery. JQuery would make you life tons easier :)

```js
var score = 0;

function start_game() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("redbox").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("redbox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  }, 2000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("greenbox").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("greenbox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  }, 3000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("bluebox").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("bluebox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("yellowbox").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  }, 4000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("yellowbox").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  }, 5000);

  setInterval(function() {
    start_game()
  }, 5500);

}

document.getElementById("redbox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target.style.backgroundColor == "red") {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =  score + 1;
    alert("You got a point!");
  }
});
document.getElementById("greenbox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target.style.backgroundColor == "green") {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =  score + 1;
    alert("You got a point!");
  }
});
document.getElementById("bluebox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target.style.backgroundColor == "blue") {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =  score + 1;
    alert("You got a point!");
  }
});
document.getElementById("yellowbox").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if(e.target.style.backgroundColor == "yellow") {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML =  score + 1;
    alert("You got a point!");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

.bigbox {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#bluebox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

#redbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

#yellowbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

#greenbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<DIV class="container">
  <CENTER>
    <DIV onclick="" id="redbox"> </DIV>
    <DIV onclick="" id="greenbox"> </DIV>
    <DIV onclick="" id="bluebox"> </DIV>
    <DIV onclick="" id="yellowbox"> </DIV>
  </CENTER>
</DIV>

<BR>
<BR>

<DIV class="container" style="background-color: grey;">
  <CENTER>
    <BR>
    <button onclick="start_game()"> Start game </button> </CENTER>
</DIV>
<BR>
<BR>

<DIV class="bigbox">
  Press "Start Game" to begin. <br> Score
  <p id="score"> 0 </p>

</DIV>
```